# JSZipUtils undefined using Meteor

Tags: meteor, jszip

I have been trying to use `JSZip` to download image files to the client. Many solutions I have come across use `JSZipUtils` to extract the data required for the image when passed to `JSZip`.

What I have so far:

```js
var logoUrl = '/images/logo.jpg';

const downloadPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
  JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(logoUrl, (err, data) => resolve(data));
});

zip.file('logo.jpg', downloadPromise);

zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"}).then(function(content) {
  saveAs(content, "example.zip");
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

The problem seems to be with `JSZipUtils`, which I thought was added as part of the `udondan:jszip` package. To my dismay, it wasn't.

Could anyone tell/show me how to add `JSZipUtils` to my Meteor project, as there doesn't seem to be a package available?

Comment: Could you show the error?

Comment: I only receive an error if I remove the promise declaration. Within dev tools in ie11 I receive JSZipUtils  undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the import declaration at the top of my meteor js file.

```
import JSZipUtils from "/client/lib/jszip-utils.js"
```

After adding this I was able to use the **JsZipUtils** library.

There is a lack of documentation out there to assist with this.

I hope this can help someone else!